# Does boric acid catalyze esterifications with isopropanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, esters

I am going to synthetise isopropyl salicylate. From what I have read on phillysim.org ([pdf](http://phillysim.org/newmanual/exp15.pdf)) the formation of ethyl salicylate can be catalyzed by boric acid. I could use sulfuric acid but it would be much more convenient with boric acid.
Ethanol and isopropanol have some differences, so I am not sure if it works for both of them.

Has anyone tried this? Does it work? Would it be better to just use sulfuric acid?

Comment: According to
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01178939

It looks like it works, but probably the "milder" conditions required by sulfuric acid (plus its dehydrating power) make it preferable.

A secondary alcohol (isopropanol) should not be a problem anyway